# How to get the location coordinates at which we are present using program

Tags: blackberry, geolocation

I am working on a project which get the current location coordinates and sends them to a server where server gets the street address with the coordinates sent by Blackberry mobile. And this project is to be done on 8520 blackberry mobile without using GPS. Is it possible to get the location without using GPS and without depending on third party members? Please help me with a code if it is possible. Thank you

Comment: [[How to get location without GPS in Blackberry](http://blog.vimviv.com/blackberry/location-gps-blackberry/)]

Comment: @Vivart thank so much it really helped me. But when i am running the application with the code i found i got an excepion: Application terminated: denied the "Location Data" permission. How to resolve this?

Comment: You have to grant permission to the app in the device's Application Management section.  You should have been prompted for permission the first time your app tried to access the Location.  Otherwise, you can go into the device's Application Management section and tweak the permissions manually.  On my Torch 9800, clicking on an app and choosing "Edit Permissions", "Location Data" is located in the "Connections" list of permissions.  In your code, make sure to wrap the API access with a try/catch block to catch exceptions, such as ControlledAccessException, so your app is not terminated.

Comment: Thank you. But is there any other way to get the location without depending on third party members

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following links which gives very useful information about locations services in blackberry

[Location-Based Services](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/lbs-summary.html#GPS)

[Location APIs – Start to finish](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Location-APIs-Start-to-finish/ta-p/571949)

Google provides location apis which you can use to find out the lat/longs. Its very easy. All you do is create a json request with your current cellid , and send the request to google. You get the lat/long from the google response.

Comment: than.. i have blackberry 8310 os 4.5 and 9550 os5.0 .. 8310 have carrier and google map application is working fine  but when i m going in setting>advance optiopn>gps and refresh gps it continuously show me for searching satellite... so how to get current lat long without gps ? and my 9550 have no sim its working using wifi and also cant get current lat long using gps  ?? my location is Ahmedabad ..is gps working in india?